# WPF Insert variable in TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock

Is it possible to bind "AMOUNT" with it's value (i.e. update with corresponding global variable) using only XAML? If not, what i have write to replace AMOUNT with my var before showing the page?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvtfR.png

```
<TextBlock Height="231" Canvas.Left="120" TextWrapping="Wrap" Canvas.Top="459" Width="840" 
           FontFamily="Neo Sans Pro" FontSize="48" 
           Foreground="#FF006CB7" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center">
  <Run Text="Для перечисления "/>
  <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="AMOUNT"/>  
  <Run Text=" рублей в помощь детям с помощью банковской карты, пожалуйста, следуйте инструкции:"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a binding to a variable in your code-behind.

```
Text="{Binding AMOUNT}"
```

If this is - as you describe - a "global variable", you can bind like so:

```
Text="{x:Static wpfApplication1:Globals.Amount}"
```

The global variable definition could look like this:

```
public class Globals
{
    public static string Amount = "5000";
}
```

Note that the Text property of your text box requires a string.

Comment: Very nice static binding. You can also get your application .Settings files similarly this way.

Answer (score 1):

Using MVVM; in very broad strokes :

1. Create a class with a string property: e.g.

   public class MyViewModel
   {
       public string Amount { get { return "..."; } }
   }
2. Assign an instance of the class above to the DataContext of the view.

   var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
   view.DataContext = viewModel;
3. Using a binding expression in the XAML

   ...TextBlock Text="{Binding Amount}"... />